# Using MSAL to obtain tokens for MS Graph without overriding custom app authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm building a .NET 6 ASP.NET app that has custom authentication. I need to call MS Graph APIs on behalf of my users and I want to use MSAL for that. Unfortunately, all examples include signing in the users to the app via Azure AD. I do not want MSAL to override my custom authentication, I just want to obtain the access/refresh tokens and I will tie them in with my local user principals.

This is the example code I'm looking to modify:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new[] { "User.Read" })
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I could manually craft all the OAuth 2.0 messages but surely MSAL can do that for me without overriding my app's User.Current? Any tips, examples?

Comment: You should know that if you want to call ms graph api for the user, then you should know who is this user(I mean you need to get, for example the user id), then you can call graph api now. So if you don't use ms identity platform but only use your own authentication, you can't get the user's information in azure ad, then nothing can be done. How you link your own authentication to azure ad users?

Comment: The user needs to sign in using Azure AD in to your app in order for you to call MS Graph as them.

Comment: @TinyWang Sure, the user needs to sign in to Azure AD and I will get back an auth token that contains all the information the Graph needs, including user ID  - this is the normal OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow. What I don't want is overriding my local signed in principal in ASP.NET